# New help saving data in Mudblazor dialog

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Here's my code:

```
@inject IThemeService ThemeService
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudDialog Style="min-width: 500px;">
    <TitleContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">
            @if (@theme.Id == 0)
            {
                <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddBox" Class="mr-3 mb-n1" />
                <span>Add a Theme?</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddBox" Class="mr-3 mb-n1">Edit Theme?</MudIcon>
                <span>Edit a Theme?</span>
            }
        </MudText>
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
        <MudTextField Value="@theme.Id.ToString()" Label="Theme ID" ReadOnly="true" />
        <MudTextField Value="@theme.Title" Label="Theme Name" />
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Error" OnClick="SaveTheme">Save Theme</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Theme theme { get; set; } = new Theme();

    private void Cancel()
    {
        MudDialog.Cancel();
    }

    private async void SaveTheme()
    {
        if (theme.Id == 0)
        {
            await ThemeService.CreateTheme(theme);
            Snackbar.Add("Theme Created!", Severity.Success);
        }
        else 
        {
            await ThemeService.UpdateTheme(theme);
            Snackbar.Add("Theme Updated!", Severity.Success);
        }

        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(theme.Id));
        ThemeService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Why would is not save the fields I enter in the dialog?  It creates a new record in the db, but the Title field is empty.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I'm no MudBlazor expert, but edit fields must work like normal Blazor fields.  You are simply setting the value, not binding the Field to the model property.  Check the MudBlazor documentation on using `@bind-Value` and the Ms-Docs documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?msclkid=29f8e320a88d11ecae8500876dd31546&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is one way (from variable to page control). The simplest option for making it two way is to @bind

```
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="theme.Id" Label="Theme ID" ReadOnly="true" />
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="theme.Title" Label="Theme Name" />
```